# InvalidCastException When Calling Attach Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I once again have a very strange problem with the Entity Framework.

I want to:

Send a hashset of objects to a method

Load these objects from the database

Update one of the fields in each of the objects

Save the objects back to the database, either all at once or individually

Some of my code is:

```
For Each BI As GeneralBasketItem In UsedDiscItems
Using db As New Till1Entities1 
db.GeneralBasketItem.Attach(BI)
```

''I tried having the context outside and inside the for each to experiment with this.

Part of the DB schema:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvt4K.jpg

The last line is sometimes, not always throwing the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147467262
>     Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.PromAppliedPromDisc_052D0BC99A5A9E842B5774E34C71C0ADE6170E70600ADE549AAA5F0EEA48E49F' to type 'CoreTillDAL.PromBaskItemDisc'.
>     Source=System.Data.Entity
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.AddToLocalCache(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints)
>          at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfSingleRelationship(RelatedEnd relatedEnd, NavigationProperty n, Object o)
>          at System.Data.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships()
>          at System.Data.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships`1.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships(EntityEntry entry)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName)
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
>          at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
>          at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
>          at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
>          at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
>          at CoreTillDAL.PromSetPrice.AdjustBaskItems(HashSet`1 UsedDiscItems) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\DBPromPlugin1\Plugins Classes\PromAndDisc\PromSetPriceE.vb:line 60
>          at CoreTillDAL.GeneralBasket.AdjustBIsforProms() in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\DBPromPlugin1\Core Classes\EF Ext Classes\Till\GeneralBasketE.vb:line 245
>          at CoreTillDAL.GeneralBasket.ApplyBIandBaskDiscounts() in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\DBPromPlugin1\Core Classes\EF Ext Classes\Till\GeneralBasketE.vb:line 174
>          at CoreTillDAL.PotAppliedProm.SavePromotionToBasketorItems(Int64 PromIDForThisVal, Boolean ManualActivation, Int64 BasketID, Dictionary`2 UsedBuyItems, Boolean test) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\DBPromPlugin1\Plugins Classes\PromClasses\PotentialProms\PotAppliedProm.vb:line 172
>          at PromPlugin.DPromAutoApplicator.ApplyBestPromotiontoItems() in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\PromDomainPlugin\AutoPromotions\DPromAutoApplicator.vb:line 92
>          at PromPlugin.DPromAutoApplicator.CalcandApplyPromsToBasket(GeneralBasketItem NewBasketItem) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\PromDomainPlugin\AutoPromotions\DPromAutoApplicator.vb:line 59
>          at PromPlugin.DPromController.HandleBaskItemAdded(Object o, BaskItemAddedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\PromDomainPlugin\AutoPromotions\DPromController.vb:line 53
>          at CoreTillDAL.CoreTill.AddBasketItem(Int64 BasketID, Int64 ProductID) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\DBPromPlugin1\Core Classes\EF Ext Classes\Till\CoreTill.vb:line 29
>          at UnitTests.TestingStoredProcs.addBasketItemsToTriggerProm(GeneralBasket Basket, Int64 PromID, DPromController& PromCont) in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\UnitTests\TestingStoredProcs.vb:line 545
>          at UnitTests.TestBasicTests.TestAllBasicPromsAuto() in C:\Users\neil.clarke\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Plugins\UnitTests\TestClasses\TestBasicTests.vb:line 265
>     InnerException:

I have no idea why. As you may be able to see the two types referenced:

PromAppliedPromDisc
PromBaskItemDisc

Are not the type I am trying to attach (GeneralBasketItem) so I am unsure as to why they are even mentioned.
PromAppliedPromDisc is a Navigation property (FK) of GeneralBasketItem. PrombaskitemDisc is a Navigation property (FK) of PromAppliedPromDisc.

I have also seen this problem when EF was trying to cast one of the navigation properties to the generalbasketitem type.

Can anyone help? I haven't found any similar problems online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found cleaning my solution and rebuilding has been getting rid of this error for now.

I guess its one of those VS bugs.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered this problem it turned out that the Id field in my table was set as an identity but it was not marked as the primary key. I fixed it with:

```
alter TABLE [dbo].[Log] add CONSTRAINT [PK_Id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

.. and then regenerating the model from the database.